# How to sort by Date with DataTables jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-plugins

I am using the datatables jquery plugin and want to sorty by dates.

I know they got a plugin but I can't find where to actually download it from

http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting

I believe I need this file: dataTables.numericComma.js yet I can't find it anywhere and when I download datatables it does not seem to be in the zip file.

I am also not sure if I need to make my own custom date sorter to pass into this plugin.

I am trying to sort this format MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM TT(AM |PM)

Thanks

**Edit**

How can I change this to sort by MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM TT(AM |PM) and change it to U.S date?

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-asc']  = function(a,b) {
    var ukDatea = a.split('/');
    var ukDateb = b.split('/');

    var x = (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    var y = (ukDateb[2] + ukDateb[1] + ukDateb[0]) * 1;

    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-desc'] = function(a,b) {
    var ukDatea = a.split('/');
    var ukDateb = b.split('/');

    var x = (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    var y = (ukDateb[2] + ukDateb[1] + ukDateb[0]) * 1;

    return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ?  -1 : 0));
};
```

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for this code. I was actually having trouble sorting UK dates and many threads I found had code that didn't work, this does, so again thank you!

Comment: I know this is a very old question, and answers are old too. As of writing this comment, [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33568433/2628243) given by @RenRen works perfect and seems to be the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Click on the "show details" link under **Date (dd/mm/YYY)**, then you can copy and paste that plugin code provided there

---

Update: I think you can just switch the order of the array, like so:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-asc']  = function(a,b) {
    var usDatea = a.split('/');
    var usDateb = b.split('/');

    var x = (usDatea[2] + usDatea[0] + usDatea[1]) * 1;
    var y = (usDateb[2] + usDateb[0] + usDateb[1]) * 1;

    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-desc'] = function(a,b) {
    var usDatea = a.split('/');
    var usDateb = b.split('/');

    var x = (usDatea[2] + usDatea[0] + usDatea[1]) * 1;
    var y = (usDateb[2] + usDateb[0] + usDateb[1]) * 1;

    return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ?  -1 : 0));
};
```

All I did was switch the `__date_[1]` (day) and `__date_[0]` (month), and replaced `uk` with `us` so you won't get confused. I think that should take care of it for you.

---

Update #2: You should be able to just use the date object for comparison. Try this:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-asc']  = function(a,b) {
 var x = new Date(a),
     y = new Date(b);
 return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-desc'] = function(a,b) {
 var x = new Date(a),
     y = new Date(b);
 return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ?  -1 : 0));
};
```

Comment: I will check your answer out in a few mins. I actually wa using tablesorter before I switched. I switched because I needed to use the search plugin and from what I found it is extremely hard to dynamically add rows to tablesorter when using the search plugin.

Comment: so how would I add to this hours and mins to this equation?

Comment: Try my new update... I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Answer (score 136):

### Date Sort - with a hidden element

Convert the date to the format *YYYYMMDD* and prepend to the actual value (*MM/DD/YYYY*) in the `<td>`, wrap it in an element, set style `display:none;` to the elements. Now the date sort will work as a normal sort. The same can be applied to date-time sort.

HTML

```
<table id="data-table">
   <tr>
     <td><span>YYYYMMDD</span>MM/DD/YYYY</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#data-table span {
    display:none; 
}
```

Comment: If exporting to Excel, these hidden elements still appear, fyi.

Comment: @Anulal There is an extra close tag near the YYYY. Please fix the code in your answer.

Comment: Any workarounds for avoiding the YYYYMMDD from getting generated in Print, Excel, PDFs etc.?

Comment: @amit Please try with media query to hide YYYYMMDD on print 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print-hide.css">`

Comment: Do any have solution for @waxi question? I am facing same issue

Comment: Please try clone and remove these hidden nodes before export https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239908/how-to-export-only-visible-tr-table-to-excel-with-jquery

Comment: This method is not working in Firefox, my client loves firefox -.-

Comment: You can hide columns from export width buttons.exportOptions.columns property

Answer (score 128):

**You should make use of the HTML5 Data Attributes.**
https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

Just add the **data-order** element to your **td element**.
No plugins required.

```
<table class="table" id="exampleTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Sign Up Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>Peter</td>
            <td data-order="2015-11-13 12:00">13. November 2015</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Daniel</td>
            <td data-order="2015-08-06 13:44">06. August 2015</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td data-order="2015-10-14 16:12">14. October 2015</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#exampleTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

I realize this is a two year old question, but I still found it useful.  I ended up using the sample code provided by Fudgey but with a minor mod.  Saved me some time, thanks!

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-asc']  = function(a,b) { 
  var x = new Date($(a).text()),
  y = new Date($(b).text());
  return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0)); 
}; 

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-desc'] = function(a,b) { 
  var x = new Date($(a).text()),
  y = new Date($(b).text());
  return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ?  -1 : 0)); 
};
```

Answer (score 5):

As of 2015, the most convenient way according to me to sort Date column in a DataTable, is using the [required sort plugin](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/). Since the date format in my case was `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, I ended up using the [date-euro plugin](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-euro). 
All one needs to do is:

**Step 1:** Include the sorting plugin [JavaScript file](//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.6/sorting/date-euro.js) or code and;

**Step 2:** Add `columnDefs` as shown below to target appropriate column(s).

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    columnDefs: [
       { type: 'date-euro', targets: 0 }
    ]
});
```

Comment: * Please note that this plug-in is **deprecated*. The
 * [datetime](//datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) plug-in provides enhanced
 * functionality and flexibility.

Answer (score 5):

**Only for html tables pre-loaded, if you use ajax, this is not the answer**

Datatables only can order by **DateTime in "ISO-8601"** format, so you have to convert your date in "date-order" to this format (example using Razor):

```
<td data-sort="@myDate.ToString("o")">@myDate.ToShortDateString() - @myDate.ToShortTimeString()</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone is having trouble where they have blank spaces either in the date values or in cells, you will have to handle those bits. Sometimes an empty space is not handled by trim function coming from html it's like "$nbsp;". If you don't handle these, your sorting will not work properly and will break where ever there is a blank space.

I got this bit of code from jquery extensions here too and changed it a little bit to suit my requirement. You should do the same:) cheers!

```
function trim(str) {
    str = str.replace(/^\s+/, '');
    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (/\S/.test(str.charAt(i))) {
            str = str.substring(0, i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return str;
}

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk-date-time-asc'] = function(a, b) {
    if (trim(a) != '' && a!="&nbsp;") {
        if (a.indexOf(' ') == -1) {
            var frDatea = trim(a).split(' ');
            var frDatea2 = frDatea[0].split('/');
            var x = (frDatea2[2] + frDatea2[1] + frDatea2[0]) * 1;
        }
        else {
            var frDatea = trim(a).split(' ');
            var frTimea = frDatea[1].split(':');
            var frDatea2 = frDatea[0].split('/');
            var x = (frDatea2[2] + frDatea2[1] + frDatea2[0] + frTimea[0] + frTimea[1] + frTimea[2]) * 1;
        }
    } else {
        var x = 10000000; // = l'an 1000 ...
    }

    if (trim(b) != '' && b!="&nbsp;") {
        if (b.indexOf(' ') == -1) {
            var frDateb = trim(b).split(' ');
            frDateb = frDateb[0].split('/');
            var y = (frDateb[2] + frDateb[1] + frDateb[0]) * 1;
        }
        else {
            var frDateb = trim(b).split(' ');
            var frTimeb = frDateb[1].split(':');
            frDateb = frDateb[0].split('/');
            var y = (frDateb[2] + frDateb[1] + frDateb[0] + frTimeb[0] + frTimeb[1] + frTimeb[2]) * 1;
        }
    } else {
        var y = 10000000;
    }
    var z = ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    return z;
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk-date-time-desc'] = function(a, b) {
    if (trim(a) != '' && a!="&nbsp;") {
        if (a.indexOf(' ') == -1) {
            var frDatea = trim(a).split(' ');
            var frDatea2 = frDatea[0].split('/');
            var x = (frDatea2[2] + frDatea2[1] + frDatea2[0]) * 1;
        }
        else {
            var frDatea = trim(a).split(' ');
            var frTimea = frDatea[1].split(':');
            var frDatea2 = frDatea[0].split('/');
            var x = (frDatea2[2] + frDatea2[1] + frDatea2[0] + frTimea[0] + frTimea[1] + frTimea[2]) * 1;
        }
    } else {
        var x = 10000000;
    }

    if (trim(b) != '' && b!="&nbsp;") {
        if (b.indexOf(' ') == -1) {
            var frDateb = trim(b).split(' ');
            frDateb = frDateb[0].split('/');
            var y = (frDateb[2] + frDateb[1] + frDateb[0]) * 1;
        }
        else {
            var frDateb = trim(b).split(' ');
            var frTimeb = frDateb[1].split(':');
            frDateb = frDateb[0].split('/');
            var y = (frDateb[2] + frDateb[1] + frDateb[0] + frTimeb[0] + frTimeb[1] + frTimeb[2]) * 1;
        }
    } else {
        var y = 10000000;
    }

    var z = ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
    return z;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow the link
https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18

A very easy way to integrate ordering by date.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
```

Put this code in before initializing the datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // ......
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD-MMM-YY HH:mm:ss');
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    // And any format you need
}
```

Answer (score 2):

About update#1, there are 2 problems :

- Number of days = 1 (d/MM/YYYY) instead of (dd/MM/YYYY)
- Empty date

here is the solution to avoid these problems :

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-asc'] = function (a, b) {
            var ukDatea = a.split('/');
            var ukDateb = b.split('/');

            //Date empty
             if (ukDatea[0] == "" || ukDateb[0] == "") return 1;

            //need to change Date (d/MM/YYYY) into Date (dd/MM/YYYY) 
            if(ukDatea[0]<10) ukDatea[0] = "0" + ukDatea[0]; 
            if(ukDateb[0]<10) ukDateb[0] = "0" + ukDateb[0];

            var x = (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
            var y = (ukDateb[2] + ukDateb[1] + ukDateb[0]) * 1;

            return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        };

        //Sorting by Date 
        jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-desc'] = function (a, b) {
            var ukDatea = a.split('/');
            var ukDateb = b.split('/');

             //Date empty
             if (ukDatea[0] == "" || ukDateb[0] == "") return 1;

            //MANDATORY to change Date (d/MM/YYYY) into Date (dd/MM/YYYY) 
            if(ukDatea[0]<10) ukDatea[0] = "0" + ukDatea[0]; 
            if(ukDateb[0]<10) ukDateb[0] = "0" + ukDateb[0];

            var x = (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
            var y = (ukDateb[2] + ukDateb[1] + ukDateb[0]) * 1;

            return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a hidden column "dateOrder" (for example) with the date as string with the format "yyyyMMddHHmmss" and use the property "orderData" to point to that column.

```
var myTable = $("#myTable").dataTable({
 columns: [
      { data: "id" },
      { data: "date", "orderData": 4 },
      { data: "name" },
      { data: "total" },
      { data: "dateOrder", visible: false }
 ] });
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the column's `type` as `type: 'date'`:

`{title: 'Expiration Date', data: 'ExpirationDate', type: 'date'}`

Answer (score 0):

I got solution after working whole day on it. It is little hacky solution Added span inside td tag

```
<td><span><%= item.StartICDate %></span></td>.
```

Date format which Im using is dd/MM/YYYY. Tested in Datatables1.9.0

Answer (score 0):

I Have 10 Columns in my table and there is 2 columns of dates, 2nd column and 4th column is of US Date, so this is worked for me fine. Just paste this code at last in your script section in same sequence.

```
   jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-asc'] = function (a, b) {
        var x = new Date(a),
            y = new Date(b);
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    };


    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-desc'] = function (a, b) {
        var x = new Date(a),
            y = new Date(b);
        return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
    };


    $('#tblPoSetupGrid').dataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            { type: 'us_date', targets: 3 },
            { type: 'us_date', targets: 1 }
        ]

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for mm/dd/yyyy (or yy) dates if the dates all come after 1970:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['formatted-date-asc'] = function (x, y) {
    'use strict';
    x = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", x).getTime();
    y = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", y).getTime();
    return x - y;
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['formatted-date-desc'] = function (x, y) {
    'use strict';
    x = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", x).getTime();
    y = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", y).getTime();
    return y - x;
};
```

To use in a dataTable:

```
$('#data-table').dataTable({
"bSort": true,
"aoColumnDefs": [
    { "sType": "formatted-date", "aTargets": [ 0,1 ] }
]
```

});