# How to export only visible tr table to excel with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some table combine with this plugin https://github.com/btechco/btechco_excelexport to export data to excel. And then i control the table with checkbox to show or hide specific column of table like this.

But, how to i can export to excel only visible tr table ?

**Table.**

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="blabla" checked="checked">Column 1
<input type="checkbox" value="blabla" checked="checked">Column 2
<input type="checkbox" value="blabla" checked="checked">Column 3
</div>

<button id="btnExport">Export</button>
<table id="tableexport">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>123456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Anne</td>
      <td>987654</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Nikki</td>
      <td>786578</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

**Hide and Show tr table**

```
$(document).on('change', 'div input', function() {
        var checked = $(this).is(":checked");

        var index = $(this).parent().index();
            $('table thead tr ').each(function() {
                if(checked) {
                    $(this).find("th").eq(index).show();
                } else {
                    $(this).find("th").eq(index).hide(); 
                }
            });

            $('table tbody tr ').each(function() {
                if(checked) {
                    $(this).find("td").eq(index).show();
                } else {
                    $(this).find("td").eq(index).hide(); 
                }
            });
    });
```

And this code to export table to excel. (Plugin)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnExport").click(function () {
                $("#tableexport").btechco_excelexport({
                    containerid: "tableexport"
                   , datatype: $datatype.Table
                });
            });
    });
```

Comment: On export you could run thru the table, check it's visibility and write the visible content to an object and send this to your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnExport").click(function () {
            $("#tableexport").clone(true, true)
                             .find(':not(:visible)').remove()
                             .end().prop('id', 'customId').btechco_excelexport({
                                 containerid: "customId"
                                , datatype: $datatype.Table
                             });
    });
});
```

It clone the table and remove everything that is not visible then export that table.

Comment: Thanks Karl. But what should i write in id and customid. Because when i try like this, the code do not working.
.end().prop('#tableexport', '#tableexport2').btechco_excelexport({
       containerid: "tableexport2"
       , datatype: $datatype.Table

Comment: @user3089464 No no no, `.prop('id', 'yourCustomIdHere)` change the id of the table for your custom id. You should not have 2 elements with the same id, that's why you change it :) Since you changed the id, you'll need to change it in the `containerid` param.

Comment: Like **user3089464**, after implementing @Karl-AndréGagnon's code, the button stopped functioning. The code make sense, but why doesn't the button work??

Comment: @gmaggio I would like to help you, but without an code example, i can't really put my finger on what's wrong.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I'm so sorry. You are right. But after further investigation, turns out the plugin **user3089464** and I used, ie. [jquery.btechco.excelexport.js](https://github.com/battatech/battatech_excelexport), cannot print the cloned element without it being inserted into the page first. I will provide the code in the answer section.

Comment: It seems that `.find(':not(:visible)').remove()` is finding all elements and removing them because the cloned table is not visible.  I used a class selector instead, e.g. `.find(tr.hidden)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a modification of **@Karl-AndréGagnon** answer. It just turns out the plugin used, ie. [jquery.btechco.excelexport.js](https://github.com/battatech/battatech_excelexport), cannot print the cloned element without it being inserted into the page first.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btnExport").click(function() {

        $('#customId').remove();

        $("#tableexport").clone(true, true)
            .find(':not(:visible)').remove()
            .end().prop('id', 'customId')
            .insertAfter('#tableexport')
            .css('display','none')
            .btechco_excelexport({
                containerid: "customId"
                    , datatype: $datatype.Table
            });

    });

});
```

Comment: Good addition. You could also remove the table after the export for a cleaner HTML.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yes, I have considered that but unfortunately after the plugin's execution (`btechco_excelexport()`) any processes in the following stack seems to be ignored. It could be the plugin's limitation. Either that or I might be doing it wrong.. :P

Comment: Maybe the plugin doesn't return the jquery object so you can't chain.

Comment: Maybe.. I'm not sure. All I know is that it converts HTML table into excel file for saving.