# Datatable columndef not working for dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, date, datatables

I have a date column in this format dd/mm/yyyy for bootstrap datatable. I try to sort it had issues. So I tried to insert this columndef. The results is same the sorting is not correct still.

```
var table = $('#listTable').DataTable({
        responsive:true,

        "columnDefs": [
         { type: 'date-euro', targets: 0 }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: please follow the steps which is in this link `https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-eu`

Comment: So I must include that extra plugin I have read it not so clear can you help me describe?

Comment: If you see the link it gives this codes columnDefs: [
       { type: 'date-eu', targets: 0 }
     ] so this what I followed accordingly?

Comment: yes , you have to add that extra plugin. check this link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862322/how-to-sort-by-date-with-datatables-jquery-plugin`

Comment: you can mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this plugin for this:

Refer this link : [click here](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-eu)

Add this code:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-eu-pre": function ( date ) {
        date = date.replace(" ", "");

        if ( ! date ) {
            return 0;
        }

        var year;
        var eu_date = date.split(/[\.\-\/]/);

        /*year (optional)*/
        if ( eu_date[2] ) {
            year = eu_date[2];
        }
        else {
            year = 0;
        }

        /*month*/
        var month = eu_date[1];
        if ( month.length == 1 ) {
            month = 0+month;
        }

        /*day*/
        var day = eu_date[0];
        if ( day.length == 1 ) {
            day = 0+day;
        }

        return (year + month + day) * 1;
    },

    "date-eu-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "date-eu-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );
```

this is for datatable define:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
     columnDefs: [
       { type: 'date-eu', targets: 0 }
     ]
  } );
```

you can also find your answer from this stack overflow link:[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862322/how-to-sort-by-d%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bate-with-datatables-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bjquery-plugin)

Comment: I have added those codes and saved as a date-eu.js same folder as where my jquery.dataTables.min.js and dataTables.bootstrap.min.js is. But it doesnt seem to be working properly.

Comment: are you add date-eu.js file in your page?

Comment: you had check that stackoverflow refresh link ?

Comment: Yes I have added the date-eu.js in my page too. I have checked and followed the link too