# DataTables issue with descending dates and times out of order

Tags: javascript, datatables

I've been successful in formatting the dates I get back from my API however they are not being sorted correctly in DataTables. Here is my JS code:

```
function GetActivityLog(nodeId, domainName, computerName) {

$.ajax({
    url: **removed**,
    success: function (json) {
        table = $('#tblActivityLogs').DataTable({
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        });
        table.clear();
        table.rows.add(json).draw();
        $('#nodeName').html(computerName);
    }
})
```

}

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tblActivityLogs').DataTable({
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        "autoWidth": false,
        columnDefs: [
            { targets: 0, class: 'dt-body-nowrap', title: 'Date/Time', data: 'dateTime' , render: function (data) { return moment(data).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') } },
            { targets: 1, title: 'Type', data: 'entryType' },
            { targets: 2, title: 'Event ID', data: 'eventId' },
            { targets: 3, class: 'dt-body-wrap', title: 'Message', data: 'message' }
        ]
    });
})
```

It was easiest to snip a few pictures of what I see happening:

[image: datatablesimage]

As you can see, the descending dates flip between old, to recent, and back to older dates. Even on the same day the times are messed up. Here is a clip of the original array containing the un-formatted date:

[image: array]

`GetActivityLog` is called with an `onClick` event but it was my understanding that the `$(document).ready` code lays the foundational elements and formatting for the datatable so the event can populate the table when called.

**Note:** The image of the array item is the first in the array yet it's showing up as the fifth item in the image (March 12th @ 4:39AM) within the table.

### Update

I've had better success in formatting the data with `moment` as follows:

```
return moment(data).format('MMMM DD YYYY, h:mm:ss')
```

Looks like DataTables can sort the day correctly now however the time is still not sorting (the newest time for the day is the oldest in the list for that day).

Comment: Looks like its sorting the date as a String, this question may prove helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862322/how-to-sort-by-date-with-datatables-jquery-plugin

Comment: Instead of formatting date and time while data table rendering , just get formatted date and time in your json response and do proper calculation of it in your file pointing to url in your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, but unfortunately, without further help, javascript isn't great at intuitively sorting number arrays. For example:

```
var arr = [5,1,13,20,3];
arr.sort() returns [1,13,20,3,5];
```

So you have to give it a function to help it deal not just with the first digit, then second digit (if any, and so on), but to think in terms of 10 > 2.

I'm sure you already know:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});  // asc
arr.sort(function(a,b){return b - a}); // desc
```

Check out this link for a plug-in code to help sort by datetime properly: 
https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/datetime-moment

I hope this helps.