# Datatables date sort vs date display

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables to display a table and I am pulling a list of datestimes from a MySQL database. These date times are not standard dates and look like this:

```
12/30/19 @ 04:17 pm
```

How can I sort these accurately with Datatables?

Here is my code:

```
getRes(function (result) { // APPLIED CALLBACK
  $('#resdatatable').DataTable({
     data: result,             // YOUR RESULT
     order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
     autoWidth: false,
     responsive: true,
      columns: [
        { data: 'id', title: 'ID' },
        { data: 'bookingdatetime', title: 'Booking Date' },
        { data: 'name', title: 'Name' },
        { data: 'class', title: 'Class' },
        { data: 'pickupdatetime', title: 'Pick up' },
        { data: 'duration', title: 'Duration' },
        { data: 'dropdatetime', title: 'Drop off' },
        { data: 'age', title: 'Age' },
        { data: 'coverage', title: 'Coverage' },
        { data: 'quote', title: 'Quote' },
        {
          data: 'status',
          title: 'Status',
          render: function(data, type, row) {
            let isKnown = statusList.filter(function(k) { return k.id === data; }).length > 0;
            if (isKnown) {
              return $('<select id="resstatus'+row.id+'" onchange="changeResStatus('+row.id+')" data-previousvalue="'+row.status+'">', {
                id: 'resstatus-' + row.id, // custom id
                value: data
              }).append(statusList.map(function(knownStatus) {
                let $option = $('<option>', {
                  text: knownStatus.text,
                  value: knownStatus.id
                });
                if (row.status === knownStatus.id) {
                  $option.attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
                return $option;
              })).on('change', function() {
                changeresstatus(row.id); // Call change with row ID
              }).prop('outerHTML');
            } else {
              return data;
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
});

/**
 * jQuery plugin to convert text in a cell to a dropdown
 */
(function($) {
  $.fn.createDropDown = function(items) {
    let oldTxt = this.text();
    let isKnown = items.filter(function(k) { return k.id === oldTxt; }).length > 0;
    if (isKnown) {
      this.empty().append($('<select>').append(items.map(function(item) {
        let $option = $('<option>', {
          text: item.text,
          value: item.id
        });
        if (item.id === oldTxt) {
          $option.attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
        return $option;
      })));
    }
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);

// If you remove the renderer above and change this to true,
// you can call this, but it will run once...
if (false) {
  $('#resdatatable > tbody tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    $(tr).find('td').last().createDropDown(statusList);
  });
}


function getStatusList() {
  return [{
    id: 'Confirmed',
    text: 'Confirmed'
  }, {
    id: 'Unconfirmed',
    text: 'Unconfirmed'
  }, {
    id: 'Communicating',
    text: 'Communicating'
  }, {
    id: 'Open',
    text: 'Open'
  }, {
    id: 'Closed',
    text: 'Closed'
  }, {
    id: 'Canceled',
    text: 'Canceled'
  }, {
    id: 'Reallocated',
    text: 'Reallocated'
  }, {
    id: 'No Show',
    text: 'No Show'
  }];
}
```

I need to sort `bookingdatetime`, `pickupdatetime`, `dropdatetime` accurately (they are currently being converted into MM/DD/YY in the PHP script)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort by Date with DataTables jquery plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862322/how-to-sort-by-date-with-datatables-jquery-plugin)

Comment: @andrewjames - no sorry, I updated my question to reflect why.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can prepend hidden `<span>` elements containing the respective unix timestamps in the cells that have dates (by manually parsing the dates). Then using such columns to sort alphabetically would practically sort time-wise.